# Meaning of (collider1)x(collider2) in phenomenology papers

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, scattering-cross-section

In some phenomenology papers in particle physics, often the cross section is shown as a function of some parameter of the model given a certain centre of mass energy of a specific collider. However, sometimes the product (?) of two colliders is shown, (collider1)x(collider2).  What does that mean?  Is this some kind of combination of both colliders data or something else?

Here is an example from the introduction of https://arxiv.org/abs/1811.10313 :

> As shown in Ref. [9], the general amplitude of $\Delta L =2$ process is proportional to the Majorana neutrino mass, and the light Majorana neutrino contribution is strongly suppressed due to the small neutrino mass, we only consider the heavy Majorana neutrino. The mixing parameter between electron and the heavy Majorana neutrino is strictly constrained [26,27] and the tau lepton is hard to be reconstructed, therefore we purely concentrate on the di-muon production channel at future $e^{-}p$ colliders, e.g. LHeC [28], FCC-ep [29], ILC$\otimes$FCC [30].

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really a CERN insider - I just work at CERN, these are just vague things I recall hearing, so apologies if I get some details wrong.

Pending about a hundred billion in funding, CERN plans to build the FCC, a 100km ring which will initially do $e^+$, $e^-$ collisions then later hadron collisions. I can't remember if its after FCC's construction or after FCC's experimental completion, but they intend to also build a $50\text{ km}$ linear collider (sometimes called CLIC and sometimes called ILC, I think because there are actually two linear collider collaborations working on designs for this linear collider and CLIC is only one).

This notation isn't a well-established accelerator notation, but it means the cited paper is proposing using both FCC and ILC to collide electrons with protons. They want to collide hadrons accelerated by the FCC with electrons accelerated by the linear accelerator. The claim is that this would achieve some kind of interesting center of mass energy and presumably one could study processes that one couldn't study with just an electron positron collider or just a hadron collider. And this wouldn't be nominally possible with just a circular collider, whose magnets and accelerators would need to be optimized for just hadrons or just electrons. Unfortunately [this presentation](https://indico.cern.ch/event/1017117/contributions/4290142/attachments/2218007/3755600/LC_Plans_and_Opportunities.pdf) clarifies that the current plan for the linear collider is *not* to be tangential to the FCC. Rather it's set up so that the first building stage (the first third of the length) spans between the CERN Meyrin and Prevessin sites, presumably for logistic reasons. So this author would have some political legwork to do to convince CERN to incorporate this idea into future collider designs.

Comment: Hi AXensen, thank you very much for your reply. On the paper you have plots for the ILC⊗FCC collider and a centre-of-mass collision energy of 10 TeV's is associated to this mysterious collider. So I'm actually interesting in knowing what it actually means.

Comment: @StackExchanger yep. I'm an idiot. I took only a cursory look at the paper and came to the wrong conclusion. I've edited my answer

Comment: Hi AXensen, thanks a lot for your great answer. However I'm not sure I understand where the 10 TeV comes from, as the energy of the hardons in the FCCeh is 1.5 TeV and the 750 GeV of the electrons in the ILC, I don't see how they can reach 10 TeV?

Comment: @StackExchanger The hadrons accelerated in the FCC-hh are supposed to be 50TeV each (obviously should be higher than the 7TeV of the LHC). Presumably if you collided hadrons from the FCC and electrons from the linac, 50TeV would be your hadron energy. I don't know anything about FCCeh. I believe the relevant equation would then be $\sqrt{s}=2\sqrt{50*0.75}\text{ TeV}=6$... which is closeish to 10? (Reminder that if the two energies aren't equal you can't just add them without some relativity stuff)